# In xmonad, how to remap CapsLock to Ctrl?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm new to xmonad, and trying to remap CapsLock to Ctrl.

I think I can do this by adding a `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` file as suggested at this [xmonad setup tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/114728/how-to-use-xmonad-a-tiling-window-manager-for-linux/), and it seems that the `xmonad.hs` file should look something like the example given at the [xmonad FAQ page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions).

```
import XMonad

main = xmonad defaultConfig
         { modMask = mod4Mask
         , terminal = "urxvt"
         }
```

I'm not sure exactly how the various fields there `modMask`, `mod4Mask`, `terminal`, and `"urxvt"` represent keyboard keys, or what field to use to represent my CapsLock and Ctrl keys.

**How exactly do I remap my CapsLock to Ctrl?**

**Is there documentation somewhere describing the field associated with each key, CapsLock, Ctrl, etc.?**

P.S. As a side-note [this](http://lists.suckless.org/dwm/0706/2715.html) mailing list item also says something about xmonad keymay rebinding, but it does not appear to be haskell.

Comment: That's not something xmonad handles, I believe. `xmodmap` is indeed one way to do this (as shown in your link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@melpomene's comment led me to seek something other than xmonad for performing the keybinding remap.

Instead I used `xmodmap` following the instructions described at this blog, [Changing your caps lock into Ctrl in X](http://efod.se/writings/linuxbook/html/caps-lock-to-ctrl.html).